# Swift CloudKit CoreData Remote Change Notification also firing for local changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a CoreData setup with a *Local* store and a *Cloud* store, only the latter of which syncs with CloudKit. The sync itself works well.

I'm trying to listen for remote change notifications so that I can trigger some processes on device when a remote change from CloudKit comes in. I've set up the `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey` key in my persistence controller, and a corresponding observer that listens for this.

The observer correctly triggers for remote change notifications, however my problem is that is **also** triggers for any CoreData changes that originate on-device once the view context is saved.

If this is expected behaviour, I was hoping there would at least be some useful information in the notification itself so I could tell apart whether the change was triggered by an on-device action or synced from CloudKit.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there any other easy way to get a notification when a remote change comes in?

### Persistence Controller

```swift
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
        
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MyContainerName")
        
        let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        
        // Local
        let localUrl = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("local.store")
        let local = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: localUrl)
        local.configuration = "Local"
        
        // Cloud
        let cloudUrl = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cloud.store")
        let cloud = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: cloudUrl)
        cloud.configuration = "Cloud"
        cloud.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "my.container.identifier")
        cloud.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: "NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey")
        
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [local, cloud]
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
    }    
}
```

### App Delegate

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, selector: #selector(type(of: self).storeRemoteChange(_:)),
            name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange,
            object: PersistenceController.shared.container.persistentStoreCoordinator
        )
        return true
    }
    
    @objc
    func storeRemoteChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        precondition(notification.name == NSNotification.Name.NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange)

        print(notification.userInfo)
        
    }
    
}
```

### Output from print statement

```
Optional([AnyHashable("NSStoreUUID"): C2D121212-421B-003F-9819-956411111169, AnyHashable("storeURL"): file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3234FH#-DACF-493I-AD24-143E4CDSFE2/Library/Application%20Support/cloud.store])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If this is expected behaviour, I was hoping there would at least be some useful information in the notification itself so I could tell apart whether the change was triggered by an on-device action or synced from CloudKit.

Yes this is expected behaviour, because whether local on device or change from the cloud this is recorded as change in your store/database.

So in order to process changes from the cloud you can subscribe for database changes, read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html)

Comment: Hi @Stamenkovski, thanks for this. I've tested what you recommended and it works, however the notification appears to arrive a couple of seconds before the CoreData model updates arrive and take effect, I'm assuming this is normal.
I would like to trigger some processes when the remote notification is received, but then only after the actual CoreData changes come in.
Is there anything specific way you recommend of doing this?

Comment: I can't give you good solution for this, one way is to make your own sync. What this means is that you can use custom CKRecord without NSPersistentCloudKitContainer, and when change happens, process the changes and save the CKRecord to your custom Core Data object.

Comment: or format the data before saving to core data.